# Error 'no existe' al buscar archivo en ruta especificada

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo el siguiente código para comprobar si un archivo existe en una ruta especificada pero siempre me devuelve como que no existe. He mirado los permisos del archivo y esta todo correcto.

```
if ( System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\Temp\\test.txt")) {
  //Hago una cosa
}
else
{
  //Hago otra
}
```

Comment: Prueba asi `string curFile = @"c:\temp\test.txt";` , ten en cuenta que si no encuentra la ruta tambien retorna `false`

Comment: No funciona me devuelve false y la ruta es correcta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente sea un problema de permisos ([Documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Puedes probar de abrir el archivo en el código, por ejemplo con la instrucción `File.OpenRead` y ver si te salta alguna excepción (colocando un `try/catch`).

Esa excepción te va a dar mas información sobre el problema que tiene el archivo y porque no se puede abrir.

Ejemplo del código para probarlo:

```
try
{
    FileStream f = File.OpenRead("C:\\Temp\\test.txt");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

De no ser tema de permisos y la excepción te siga dando el error de que no se encuentra el archivo deberías comprobar que el archivo realmente se llama `test.txt`, una de las causas principales es la opción de `Ocultar las extensiones` del explorador, que al tenerla activada puede generar confusión y que el archivo realmente se llame `test.txt.txt` y no `test.txt`.

Comment: Me devuelve lo siguiente: No se pudo encontrar el archivo 'C:\Temp\test.txt'  Pero el archivo si que esta en la ruta.

Comment: @Popularfan Entonces el error es claro, comprueba si tienes activado o no lo de ocultar las extensiones de los archivos en el explorer para ver si se llama el archivo `test.txt` o `test.txt.txt`

Comment: Es probable que como dice Marc sea tema de permisos, estas ejecutando como admin la app?

Comment: Si, ejecuto Visual Studio como administrador. Pero nada me sale el mismo error

Comment: ENCONTRADO !!! El error era que el archivo tenia la extensión oculta y se llamaba test.txt.txt Gracias a todos y Gracias Windows por tener la mania de ocultar las extensiones !!!

Comment: @Popularfan Estupendo, edito la respuesta añadiendo esta opción